# Levi subgroups of exceptional (complex) Lie groups (reference request)

Tags: lie-groups, semisimple-lie-algebras, dynkin-diagrams

I'm trying to do some explicit computations for which I need to know the maximal Levi subgroups of exceptional complex Lie groups $\mathrm{F}_4=\mathrm{F}_4(\mathbb{C})$.

Of course from the Dynkin diagram I can see for example that one maximal sub-root system is of type $B_3$ and another is of type $C_3$. By the general theory, their corresponding Levi subgroups $M$ are connected reductive of type $B_3$ and $C_3$. But the maximal torus in the center $Z(M)$ of $M$ is one dimensional. It's natural to guess that for the type $C_3$ I could get $M=\mathrm{GSp}(6)$, but I could not find a reference for this.

Could any veteran point out some related references for me (about Levi subgroups of exceptional Lie groups)? And I wonder is there a database for $\mathrm{E}_6$, $\mathrm{E}_7$, $\mathrm{E}_8$?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @DietrichBurde But how to determine thesubgroup from the Lie subalgebra? Different reductive groups may have the same Lie algebras, isn't it? (I want to know explicitly the what the subgroup is, such as $\mathrm{GSp}(6)$. So it seems that the subalgebra-subgroup correspondence is not very helpful?)